# Tunneling one page apps (e.g. Backbone)

Tags: backbone.js, request

I would like to know if it is possible to nest/tunnel javascript rendered sites.

What I mean concrete:

I got a site bugs.example.org which serves a bug tracker application built on Backbone Routers, Views and Models.

over bugs.example.org/#/mybugs we can list all our bugs.

Now I have for example a second project worksuite.example.org.
This project serves roadmaps, presentations, etc. unfortunately this worksuite app doesn't serve an independent bug tracker. Instead it has a joint venture with bugs.example.org.
Now worksuite.example.org want to include/nest the bugtracker views in its own application.

This could look like:
worksuite client calls worksuite.example.org/#/bugs now the worksuite app calls a GET to bugs.example.org/#/mybugs and does a $el.html(requestedContent).
Does this work?

Another application which *could* work similar, which I know is the google captcha service which you nest with some js

Is there a keyword for such behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how well the backbone app is architected, you can have worksuite.example.org just pull all of bugs.example.org's JS files, but use its own base html/css:

```
<!-- on bugs.example.org -->
<script src="mybackbonestuff.js"></script>
<link href="mycss.css"></link>

<!-- on worksuite.example.org -->
<script src="http://bugs.example.org/mybackbonestuff.js"></script>
<link href="worksuite.css"></link>
```

Comment: would also be possible to just grep the view (model, templates) and render it? The workspace.example.org is also a backbone app. Byside couldn't I work also with html frames?

Comment: You won't be able to grep the view because $.get from 'bugs.example.com' will not actually execute the clientside javascript. You can work with html frames, but you wont be able to override the styles on bugs.example.com from worksuite.example.com because of cross domain restrictions. However, you may be able to load it into a hidden iframe and copy the data over...